# Get logon user information on J2EE application

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm working with J2EE application and my web application has to recognize the user without authenticate using the windows logon user info.

When I create a web applciation with VB.NET I used something like that:

> Session("Login") =
>   Mid(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"),
>   Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").IndexOf("\")
>   + 2)

Do you know if it's possible to do the same on Java / Spring / Tomcat webapplication?

tnx,
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

Note that you will need to add some sort of authentication to Tomcat.  For example, if you are trying to do NTLM authentication, you can use [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/).